# Gnome Desktop Environment

Tags: 12.04, gnome, desktop-environments

I know that this may be a silly question but I'm really stucked here and I really don't know how to go on with this: how can I install Gnome in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To install Gnome 3, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

To install Gnome classic, do

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```